# Mac as a file server in network where workstations run Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, permissions

For a remote office I set up a Mac Mini to be used as file server. It was pretty easy to set up the Shared folder to be accessible by everyone on the network and I have a bash script that sets up all the ACL permissions on sub-folders. I can ssh into the server any time and edit that script and re-run it to change the permissions which I like a lot. I can only do this because the remote office is in another part of the world and is not being used by anyone while I'm doing changes. Here is part of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
RW="allow list,search,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,add_file,add_subdirectory,delete_child,writeattr,writeextattr"
R="allow list,search,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit"

chmod -RN Accounting
chmod -R +a "group:admins $RW" Accounting
chmod -R +a "group:accounting $RW" Accounting

...
```

I also use scp to sync some folders back to our NAS server here.

It all works surprisingly well, however there is one user that cannot map a drive for the Shared folder. Here is what I tried:

- Delete the user in Mac OS and re-create it, no luck
- Change the name of the user in Mac OS, no luck
- Change the name and type of the user in Windows, no luck
- Map a drive on another machine using that user's credentials, no luck
- Map a drive on this user's machine using another user's credentials, that works but I need that user's permissions on the mapped drive

Somebody suggested that Windows username/password need to match Mac username/password and it does indeed match for other users (I guess due to my laziness of keeping two sets of credentials for each user to keep notes for). It doesn't make much sense to me but I tried to ensure this problematic user has everything matching and it still doesn't work.

What else could I try? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My spider sense is screaming Service Access Control Lists (SACL). Your user may not be allowed to connect to the File Sharing Service.

Open Server.app and connect to your server. Click the server overview item on the top of the left side list of services. It should be the hostname of your server.  It's directly above the "Alerts" item. Then click the "Access" tab.

This is where you define who has permission to access services provided by your Mac Server.  All of my servers are bound to Active Directory. I can find AD groups and users in this area and grant or restrict access to services.

Here is the Apple Help Article for this process
https://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/4.0/#/apdda0a07a76

In Mac OS X Server 10.9 everyone is restricted and you must add permissions for users or groups to access services provided by your server.   In Mac OS X Server 10.10 it is the opposite.  Everyone has permissions and you must restrict users.

Hope this might be your issue